# How to attach images to Wordpress posts

Tags: wordpress, post, attachment

I have tried to attach images to post by selecting it from the media and inserting it to the post. But when using the has_post_thumbnail() function, I am not getting the result as expected. Can anyone tell me how to attach a file to the post and get the source url of the attached file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you JUST using the `has_post_thumbnail()` function?

`has_post_thumbnail()` returns a boolean (True/False) value depending on whether or not there exists a thumbnail for said post. You want to add the function: `the_post_thumbnail()` after that. Here is the code I use for post thumbnails:

```
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    the_post_thumbnail(); // show the post's thumbnail
} 
?>
```

Comment: has_post_thumbnail() is False. I have inserted image into the post.

Comment: okay. I think I know what your problem is. Instead of directly adding the images to your posts, when editing, scroll down and look at the bottom-right corner to find a panel labeled 'Featured Image'. Use that to define the post's thumbnail, instead of placing it in the post contents itself